# Clip content from remote website using javascript and Iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, iframe, clipboard

Is there any helper for Iframe in Rails ??

**EDIT:**I have a link which redirects to a remote website , i need to get the COntent from that website and store in my application is this possible , I dont need a browser extension or plugin.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect from such helper? Just use existing [content_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) or `tag` helper.